# How do I configure Ubuntu 11.04 and Windows 7 network?

Tags: networking

I am using Ubuntu 11.04 on a Dell Inspiron. I use internet through a ADSL router used my several other computers at home. I want to connect my laptop to a Toshiba Satellite with Windows 7 through LAN. I have connected a network wire between the two laptops but the Windows machine says that I am connected to an 'Unidentified network' and the Ubuntu Machine tries to connect to the network but eventually says 'Wired Network Disconnected' no matter how many times it try to connect.

There must me something wrong with my settings. Can anyone help me out? I want to eventually be able to use the same keyboard and mouse in these two machines using Synergy and I also want to share files.

Comment: I'm not totally clear on the question. What are you trying to do here? is it accessing shared folders between this two machine or else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will probably need to setup network manually on both system, since ( probably, if youre connected Dell <---> Toshiba, nothing more ) no dhcp server is running. Set ip 192.168.0.1 on one computer, 192.168.0.2 on second and on both set netmask 255.255.255.0.

Comment: wow thanks! That helped. now my Dell with the Ubuntu tells me that a connection has been established but the Toshiba with Windows 7 still cannot identify the network. 
What do I set the Gateway to? And what about the DNS?

Comment: your answer along with the once answered by Fabio fized it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Router ADSL con Wi-Fi
Ip > 192.168.0.1
Gateway 192.168.0.1
Dns 192.168.0.1
Dns 208.67.222.222
DHCP 192.168.0.2 to 192.168.0.255

Pc Xp Lan 1 Ip>198.168.0.2
Gateway 192.168.0.1
Pc Ubuntu (Lan 2) Ip>198.168.0.3
Gateway 192.168.0.1
Pc Vista (Lan 3) Ip>198.168.0.4
Gateway 192.168.0.1
Pc Seven (Lan 4) Ip>198.168.0.5 
Gateway 192.168.0.1
Pc Notebook (Wi-Fi ) 192.168.1.6
Gateway 192.168.0.1
Pc Notebook (Wi-Fi ) 192.168.1.7
Gateway 192.168.0.1
Pc Notebook (Wi-Fi ) 192.168.1.8
Gateway 192.168.0.1

Condivisione cartelle attiva

Comment: your answer along with the once answered by Denwerko fized it! Thanks!